# how to change numbers in front of a specific string in MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab

i have an input like

```
start of data

R    34
P    35.12
Pressure Ratio
END
```

in file1 I have single value 39, that I want to assign to R
in file2 I have single value 32.79 that I want to assign P

furter as the last step, before the last line END, i want to enter Radius Ratio

so that my output would be

```
R    39
P    32.79
Pressure Ratio
Radius Ratio
END
```

Part 1 is solved in linux by

```
sed '/\<R\>/!d;=;s/.* \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/;R File1.txt' inputFile.txt |
sed 'N;N;s|\n|s/|;s|\n|/|;s|$|/|;q' >temp.sed
sed -i -f temp.sed inputFile.txt
etc
```

Part 2 is solved in linux by

```
sed  -i -e '/*END/i \Radius Ratio ' inputFile.txt
```

can anyone lead a smarter way in MATLAB?

regards

Comment: I doubgt there's anything more compact or faster than `sed`. Doing this in MATLAB would only require to either program something `sed` alike or something more compact but restricted to one usecase.

Comment: ya, I know it the problem is that i dont have my program installed on linux anymore so i have to use MATLAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use something as simple as a string replacement in MATLAB, where you can still use a regular expressions? I know it is not the most elegant, but it will get the job done.

```
text = fileread('someFile.txt');
num = 100;
text = regexprep(text,'R[ ]+[0-9.]+[ ]*',['R ',num2str(num)]);
text = regexprep(text,'P[ ]+[0-9.]+[ ]*',['P ',num2str(num)]);
text = regexprep(text,'END','someString \nEND ')
```

**UPDATE**

To then write this information back to the same file or to a different file name just do the following

```
f = fopen('someFile.txt','w');
fprintf(f,text);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: pretty fine. however its not changed in the file. How can I pipe the output back into the same file??  any suggestion?